# req.body is giving empty object {} even by using bodyParser

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, body-parser

Here is my code I'm trying to make api with mysql, table in database have username and password already inserted

```js
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


const conn = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'fsoc',
    database: 'nodesql'
});
//connection 
conn.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }
    console.log('Mysql Connected');
});

//Select query

app.get('/show', (req, res) => {
    let sql = 'SELECT * from users';
    conn.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(result[0]);
    });
    console.log(req.body);
});

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('check on 3000');
})
```

Although in postman it shows the JSON data of Username and password as
`{
    "id": 2,
    "username": "ujju",
    "password": "fsoc11"
}`

Comment: it's right the fetched record in js from mysql is json, what is your problem?

Comment: can you upload postman screen shot ?

Comment: In `GET` request there's no body. That's why. If you want to receive body params, you need to send a `POST` request. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: Thanks now i understood what i was doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to replace `get` method with `post` in order to get `req.body` populated with the posted data, also in postman you have to use post request and provide some form data too:

```
app.post('/show', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req.body); //log posted data

    let sql = 'SELECT * from users';
    conn.query(sql, (err, result) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.send(result[0]);
    });

});
```